# How to call other Flows from a Record-Triggered Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

I'm working to put some best practices together for our team for developing flows, specifically taking advantage of the new record-trigger feature found in the Winter '21 release. One of the best practices I am looking at is having a single record-triggered Flow per object, so that we can control the order of execution.

However, I'm already running into a challenge with this since it seems you can create a flow for Before and After triggers, which would mean we'd need 2 flows (one before, one after) to cover those use cases. We could have a 3rd Flow for delete.

Another challenge is the it appears one cannot call other flows from a a record-triggered flow, so this means that all logic would have to be embedded into one (or 2 or 3) monolith flows, instead of calling re-useable, auto-launched flows.

So in summary, my questions are:

1. What are the best practices to create record-triggered flows to control order of execution?
2. Can record-triggered flows call auto-launched flows, and if not, why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is some basic information regarding Record-Triggered Flows on the new [Architect Site](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/trigger-automation/), but Record-Triggered Flows are still very much in development, so some things may changes as new features debut in each release.
2. There is currently no way to call subflows from Record-Triggered Flows. In that same doc, they claim a timeline of "1 Year" for that feature, but they don't specify whether that's relative to right now or some other time period.

Comment: It was updated December 2020, so the likely time frame is likely Winter 21 or Spring 22. We won't know for sure until we get there, though.